# OSI TP4 Implementation For Linux Based System

Tags: linux, networking, mac-address, osi

I am working on implementing a connection between two computers. These two computers need to communicate using an OSI TP4 connection (Mac-Address to Mac-Address). I am using a Fedora 11 Linux system. I'm trying to use C/C++ and would prefer to stay in those, though if there's no solution using them, I can be slightly flexible with this.

The second computer is already written, and I do not need to do anything with it; I just need to write code for my end in order to communicate with it. I've been searching around online trying to find either information on how to do this sort of programming or an off-the-shelf library that handles this communication, but have thus far come up empty handed.

My primary experience is with basic TCP/IP programming using the standard C libraries - however, I have no idea if I can use these for this.

I will be using the ISO 8473 Connectionless protocol for layer 3 and the ISO 8073 Class 4 model for layer 4.

Is there any information on this on the net? I can't seem to find any tutorial that explains how to do this, or any sort of example code. Again, if there's a purchasable system, that's fine too - I just need to know where I can get information on this topic.

I'm sorry if any of this is a little vague - I've never worked with stuff this low-level before and it's all pretty confusing to me at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Is this perhaps what you're after?

```
 https://kode.poss.or.id/svn/atn/trunk/module_atn/
```

An implementation of TP4/CLNP for Linux 2.6.x kernels.

More information at:

```
http://exodream.blogspot.com/2010/08/atn-tp4clnp-networking-suite-for-linux.html
```

Comment: This is definitely in the correct ballpark. I looked through this and got it installed - unfortunately, there's not much documentation (at least not that I can find) that explains exactly how to use it. I've been plugging away at it, but it's definitely a bit confusing. Something like this is definitely very, very, VERY close. Unfortunately, sans any reasonable amount of documentation, it's an uphill battle.

Comment: did you look in the directory above where there's some sample code?

Comment: Ah, there's some sample code. Doesn't compile straight out, but I'm pretty sure I can get it going if I mess around with it enough.

Thanks!